# How to switch tabs via keyboard shortcut in Firefox in reverse?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, tabs

One can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> in order to switch between tabs in Firefox, and the switch goes from left to right. But I was wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut which does it in reverse (when pressing it it goes along the tabs right to left instead) in Firefox? This would come in handy when I have many tabs open and want to move to a specific one without going completely in the other direction first if it is not in that direction.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20 and Firefox 49, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the order of traversing the tabs by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.